# Where are Smarty Template Variables Defined?

Tags: php, smarty

I am working on a program with a Smarty template,  where do the $variables come from as I see no file they are pulling from in the html. Where do I find these variables so I can edit them.  Similarly in Drupal, there are different variables available in different TPL files, because I see no includes, where is this information coming from/being pulled from, I know this is a noob question.

Comment: I think you should consult the smarty documentation first, how smarty works is explained very well there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty variables are set in the business logic via `$smarty->assign('firstName', 'Mike');`

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.assign

You can check out the Smarty.class.php source to find out where they are actually stored (they're in a member variable named `$tpl_vars`).

Answer (score 0):

The variables are defined in the PHP script files that use the templates.  Look for lines like

```
$smarty->assign( "var_name", $value );
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables are set in the PHP files that instantiate the Smarty object. You can find them by searching for the `assign()` calls. Since Smarty template do not (should not) contain PHP code in them, you won't see include calls.